# Using exec() to Match a String

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string, which I want to extract the value out. The string is something like this:

```
cdata = "![CDATA[cu1hcmod6rbg3eenmk9p80c484ma9B]]";
```

And I want `cu1hcmod6rbg3eenmk9p80c484ma9B`. In other words, I want anything inside the `![[CDATA[*]]`.

I tried to use the following javascript snippet:

```
cdata = "![CDATA[cu1hcmod6rbg3eenmk9p80c484ma9B]]";
rePattern =    new RegExp("![?:\\s+]]","m");
arrMatch = rePattern.exec( cdata );
result = arrMatch[0];
```

But the code is not working, I'm pretty sure that it's the way I how specify the matching string that's causing the problem. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var cdata = "![CDATA[cu1hcmod6rbg3eenmk9p80c484ma9B]]";
var regPattern =  /(.*CDATA\[)(.*)(\]\].*)/gm;
alert(cdata.replace(regPattern, "$2"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Your pattern should be something like...

```
/^!\[CDATA\[(.+?)\]\]$/
```

Which is...

1. Match literal starting `![CDATA[`.
2. Lazy match everything up until the closing `]` and save it in capturing group `$1` (thanks [Phrogz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405017/phrogz) for his excellent suggestion).
3. Match extra `]]`.

Your string should be available as `arrMatch[1]`.

Comment: I tried something like `rePattern =    new RegExp("/^!\[CDATA\[([^\]+)\]\]$/","m");`, but there is a syntax error.

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui Give me a minute to test it :)

Comment: @Ngu, that's a regexp literal, you don't put quotes around it: `rePattern = /^!\\[CDATA\\[([^\\]+)\\]\\]$/m;`

Comment: @NguSoonHui You are missing two backslashes in multiple spots. `new RegExp("^\\\[CDATA...`

Comment: @Phrogz, oops, thanks. Though to be precise, Ngu's comment ate some backslashes and I simply copied it. Fixed now.

Comment: @alex I added a missing square bracket to close your character class. However, given that a `]` is valid in the CDATA block, I suggest replacing `[^\\]]+` with just `.+?`.

Comment: @Phrogz Good idea - it will match in this case, but not all cases :)

Comment: @Phrogz, yup realised that 10 seconds after I edited it again. Ah the woes of backslashes. You had to put four to represent one in your comment...